(WPF)How Can I Change Disabled ListView Control Background without touching the ControlTemplate?
I Want Change Disabled Listview Background without touching the ControlTemplate.
So, I check this Site.
https://learn.microsoft.com/ko-kr/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/listview-styles-and-templates?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8
This is my xamlCode.
 <Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Visible"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Visible"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="True">
                <!--#region Working -->
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="BlueViolet"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"/>
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="40"/>
                <!--#endregion-->
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                <!--#region Not Working -->
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                <!--<Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" TargetName="PART_ScrollContentPresenter"/>-->
                <!--#endregion-->
                
                <!--#region Working -->
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="40"/>
                <!--#endregion-->
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
        <Style.Resources>
            <!--  ScrollViewer Right Bottom Corner Color  -->
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="LawnGreen"/>

            <!--  Disabled Text Color  -->
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}" Color="Red"/>
        </Style.Resources>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ListView Grid.Column="0" Margin="10" SelectedIndex="1">
        <ListViewItem Content="1" Height="100"/>
        <ListViewItem Content="2" Height="100"/>
        <ListViewItem Content="3" Height="100"/>
        <ListViewItem Content="4" Height="100"/>
        <ListViewItem Content="5" Height="100"/>
    </ListView>
    <ListView Grid.Column="1" Margin="10" SelectedIndex="1" IsEnabled="False">
        <ListViewItem Content="1" Height="100"/>
        <ListViewItem Content="2" Height="100"/>
        <ListViewItem Content="3" Height="100"/>
        <ListViewItem Content="4" Height="100"/>
        <ListViewItem Content="5" Height="100"/>
    </ListView>
</Grid>


First Try

I found the name "PART_ScrollContentPresenter" on the MS Site.
I was trying to change the background color of an object named "PART_ScrollContentPresenter" but couldn't find the TargetName.
<Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" TargetName="PART_ScrollContentPresenter"/>


Second Try

This is not working.
<Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>


Last Try

I tried changing "Style.Resource".
Using this method I was able to change the text color of a disabled Listview.
But even though I tried all the Keys in class 'SystemColors', the background color did not change.
Is there any way to change the background color without touching the ControlTemplate?
<Style.Resources>
            <!--  ScrollViewer Right Bottom Corner Color  -->
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="LawnGreen"/>

            <!--  Disabled Text Color  -->
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}" Color="Red"/>
</Style.Resources>

Edit //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
This is work. But thin white border is not disappear
<Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ScrollViewer">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>


PART_ScrollContentPresenter is a part of GridView's custom ScrollViewer template. TBH just touch the ControlTemplate, it's easy. Use original style in aero2.normalcolor.xaml file as a reference and make your own. You already have that file on your hard drive, probably in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\[your version]\DesignTools\SystemThemes\Wpf.

You need to be more clear about what you're "disabling": the entire ListView, one item, multiple items ... what? And what does it imply to be "disabled"? I show "disabled" in some  cases by changing the Opacity (same difference).
